# Use of dtype option of Python read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to speed up reading a big file by first reading the first 100 lines, determining the dtypes and then use this as input for the full read. I am having some problems with the dtype option though. It requires a dictionary but my code doesn't seem to work since all dtypes of the train variable are objects while there are others like integers and float present in the initial variable. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
import zipfile as zipf
train_zip = zipf.ZipFile('train.csv.zip')
initial = pd.read_csv(train_zip.open('train.csv'), nrows=100)
dic = dict(zip(list(initial.columns.values), initial.dtypes))
train = pd.read_csv(train_zip.open('train.csv'), dtype=dic)
```

To be clear: The dtypes from my initial dataframe are correct. Here is some sample output:

```
initial.dtypes
ID       int64
VAR_0001 object
VAR_0002 int64 
VAR_0003 int64 
VAR_0004 int64 
VAR_0005 object 
VAR_0006 int64 
VAR_0007 int64 
VAR_0008 bool 
VAR_0009 bool 
VAR_0010 bool
```

It is in the call to `dtype=dic` in the read of the train variable that something goes wrong. It appears that the dictionary is not in the right form or something since the types of train are:

```
train.dtypes
ID          object
VAR_0001    object
VAR_0002    object
VAR_0003    object
VAR_0004    object
VAR_0005    object
VAR_0006    object
VAR_0007    object
VAR_0008    object
VAR_0009    object
VAR_0010    object
```

Comment: You aren't necessary doing anything wrong.  One thing I have noticed is that any columns with all string values or with mixed types such as unicode (or str or bytes) and dates have dtype=object.  It would help to see some column data to suggest how it could be handled.

Comment: I think the problem is not in the code but in the data. Try reading the same 100 rows in the train df to see if the problem is reproduced. If not, the problem is in the data (some rows containing different types) and not in the code.

Comment: I guess you are right. Changing the number of rows read in in initial causes an error to pop up mention NAs and problems with changing from int64 to float. So it seems the data is inconsistent.
Trying `dtype=initial.dtypes.to_dict()` on a different dataset does work.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. Here is a small example illustrating that `dtype` is taken into account.

```
initial = pd.read_csv('test.csv', nrows=1)
# Dataframe to store dtypes comparison
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['initial'] = initial.dtypes
# Forcing the type from int to float
initial['begin'] = initial['begin'].astype(float)
train = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype=initial.dtypes.to_dict())
df['train'] = train.dtypes
# Correctly loaded as float
df

      initial    train
begin   int64  float64
end    object   object
zones  object   object
```

Comment: Ok, I just made a short test of your code in an example and it works fine.

Comment: I have found out what the problem is. Not really sure about the solutions yet. The dic variable holding the variable names and types should be of the form `{'VAR_0001: 'object', 'VAR_0002: 'int64', ...}`.
In stead it is of the form `{'VAR_0001: dtype('object'), 'VAR_0002: dtype('int64'), ...}`.
And since dtype returns an object array, all variables are read in as objects.

Comment: Odd since it works in the example below. Note you can use directly `initial.dtypes.to_dict()` instead of constructing the `dict`by yourself.